# How do I keep this from going over the acii value of capitals

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ascii

My if statement seems to no be working and i am confused to as of why. I need to keep the ascii value of "newcode" from going higher than the ascii value of the capitals.

```
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML  = ("<h2>&nbsp;</h2>");
 var msg= prompt("Enter your message." , " ");
 var newmsg = " ";
 var upCaseCode = 155;
 var newCode = 0;
 var usercode = 0;
 var lowCaseCode = 219;
 var specialCode = 3;
 var random_num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) + 1;
 console.log(random_num);

 //the loop encodes each letter in the message string
 for (var j = 0; j < msg.length; j++)
 {
     //check for upppercase letters and encode them
     if ((msg.charCodeAt(j) >= 65) && (msg.charCodeAt(j) <= 90))
        {   usercode = (random_num + msg.charCodeAt(j));    
                if (usercode >= 91)
                    {
                        newcode = usercode - 26;
                    }
                else (usercode <= 64)
                    {
                        newcode = usercode + 26;
                    }

                usercode = newCode;

                console.log(newCode)
        }
    else 
    //check for lowercase letters and encode them
         if ((msg.charCodeAt(j) >= 97) && (msg.charCodeAt(j) <= 122)) 
            {   newcode = ((lowCaseCode + random_num) - msg.charCodeAt(j)); }
        else
    //check for numbers and special characters and encode them
            if (((msg.charCodeAt(j) > 90) && (msg.charCodeAt(j) < 97)) || (msg.charCodeAt(j) < 65))
               {    newcode = (msg.charCodeAt(j) + specialCode);    }
    //add each encoded character to the new message
      newmsg = newmsg + " " + String.fromCharCode(newcode);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean that the `if` is not working? 1. which one 2. how is it not working - what is expected and what is happening?

Comment: It acquires a random number to add to the users input ( it adds a random to the ascii value of whatever the user types) if the random number adds an amount that goes outside the english cha ascii value then it needs to subtract 25 from the new ascii value. But the if-statement with the if-statement is not subtracting.

Comment: `newcode !== newCode` - you have a typo in your `if (usercode >= 91)`. Also, you have `else (usercode <= 64)` which should probably be `else if`

Comment: Really appreciate the feedback, it appears to be working properly now.